# Why is this causing my program to crash?

Tags: r, random, statistics

I have created the following user defined function which generates random variables using the Acceptance-Rejection Method. However, whenever it is called, my program goes on and eventually crashes or I have to force quit. I have gone through it several times. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

I am aware that this may not be the best way to have written this (Yesterday was the first time I have used R) so any extra tips are a bonus!

```
acceptReject <- function(){
  Z <- 0
  Y <- c(0,0)
  while(Y[2] < .5*(Y[1]-1)**2){
    U <- runif(2,0,1)
    Y <- log(U)
  }
  Z <- Y[1]
  U <- runif(1,0,1)
  if(U <= .5){
    Z <- abs(Z)
  }
  else{
    Z <- -abs(Z)
  }
  Z
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop.

If you assume that `Y ~ log( [0,1] )` (mathematically), that means that it always range between `log(0)` and `log(1)`, equating to `-Inf` and `0`, respectively. (Bottom line, it is always less-than-or-equal-to zero.)

Now let's look at your conditional: `.5*(Y[1]-1)**2`. If you know the *domain* of `Y` is `c(-Inf,0)`, then the *range* of this formula is

```
.5*(c(-Inf,0)-1)**2
# [1] Inf 0.5
```

(This is always greater-than-or-equal-to 0.5.)

Since `Y` is always `<= 0` and the formula is always `>= 0.5`, your conditional will mathematically always be true. Infinite loop.